# How to directly get value from array via key in node.js

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array

I'ld like to get price value directly via categoryname key in the following  array without loop with node.js. is it possible?

```
PriceItem [
    { _id: 561e92d7b5737103130a374b,
      price: ‘1000',
      categoryname: '561e7cbd288906ab3fa3b52b' }
    { _id: 561e92d7b5737103130a374c,
      price: ‘2000',
      categoryname: '561e7cc3288906ab3fa3b52c' }
    { _id: 561e92d7b5737103130a374d,
      price: ‘3000',
      categoryname: '561e3c3aabf5d47634c465bd' }
    { _id: 561e92d7b5737103130a374e,
      price: ‘4000',
      categoryname: '561e3c3eabf5d47634c465be' }
    { _id: 561e92d7b5737103130a374f,
      price: ‘5000',
      categoryname: '561e6439249dced339d529a1’ }
    ]
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It's either you do the looping or an existing function will do the loop for you.

Comment: so, if I'm doing looping, how can I get price value with categoryname key. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is acceptable:

```
function getPriceByCategory(categoryName) {
    var retVal = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < PriceItem.length; i++) {
        if (PriceItem[i].categoryname === categoryName) {
            retVal = PriceItem[i].price;
            break;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Also, I think the above data is not a multi-dimensional array but a single array of Objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arr.filter(), check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter